# How to change a particular coordinate vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

here's the code I am working on:

```
#include <inq/inq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <input/parse_xyz.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using namespace inq;
  using namespace inq::magnitude;

  input::environment env(argc, argv);
  auto comm = boost::mpi3::environment::get_world_instance();

  auto atoms = input::parse_xyz("zr.xyz");
  //atoms.push_back("Zr" | input::coord(4.8585, 7.01264, 5.172));

  auto box = input::cell::orthorhombic(9.717_A, 11.22023_A, 5.172_A);

  systems::ions ions(box, atoms);
  systems::electrons electrons(comm, ions, input::basis::cutoff_energy(30.0_Ha));
  ground_state::initial_guess(ions, electrons);

  auto result = ground_state::calculate(ions, electrons, input::interaction::pbe(), input::scf::scf_steps(200));

    double const d_0   = 9.77366;
    double const del   = 0.3257886667;
    int    const n_max = 30;


    std::ofstream ofs{"Zr_e_vs_d5.dat"};

    for(int n = 0; n != n_max; ++n){
        double const distance = d_0 - n*del;
        atoms.push_back("Zr" | input::coord(9.18123, 13.2519, distance));
        auto result = ground_state::calculate(ions, electrons, input::interaction::pbe(), input::scf::scf_steps(15));
        //ofs << distance << '\t' << zr_energy(distance) << '\n';
    ofs << distance << '\t' << result.energy.total() << '\n';
    }
 }
```

I read the 50 atom coordinates from the .xyz file. Then I push an additional atom into the vector in the loop below. I want to change the last coordinate (Z coordinate) of the atom, so as to simulate the atom moving in Z direction. I am pretty new to C++ and can't figure out how to change that particular coordinate. Please Help

Here's the input .xyz file for reference:

```
Zr    0.000000    1.870038    2.586000
Zr    9.717000    1.870038    2.586000
Zr    1.619500    4.675094    2.586000
Zr    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to to find an specific element in a vector is to use `find()`. You need to include the `<algorithm>` in your file.

```
auto ref = find(v.begin(), v.end(), element);
```

If the ref is NOT at the next of the end of the vector, which means the element is found,, the corresponding index will be:

```
if(ref != v.end()){
    int index = ref - v.begin();
}
```

Now you can access and change the element at the index in vector like this:

```
v.at(index) = newCoOrdinate;
```

That will do what you've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the library, seems like `inq` isn't a particularly popular library with much documentations, so it is well possible there's a specific api that does exactly what you want.

However, you should be able to update z coordinates using:

```cpp
for(auto & atom : atoms)
{
    atom.position += math::vector3<int>({0, 0, z_movement_distance});
}
```